# Generate multiple plot objects with vectors of equal length

Tags: matlab, plot

MATLAB will generate multiple line objects when plot is used with a vector and a scalar:

```
a = 1:4;
ph = plot(a, 1, 'o');
numel(ph) % == 4
```

And usually, it is desired that `plot` generate a [single line object for `x` and `y` arguments being vectors of the same length](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html#btzitot-1):

```
b = 1:2:8;
ph = plot(a, b, 'o');
numel(ph) % == 1
```

However, I'd like to generate a line object for each pair of values from `a` and `b`.

Note that the low-level [`line`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/line.html) function also does not create one line per column if there is just one row.

So how can I force MATLAB to generate `numel(a)` line objects in an elegant way?

The best solution I could come up with uses `arrayfun` and requires an additional step to turn the cell array into an object array:

```
hold on;
ph = arrayfun(@(x, y) plot(x, y, 'o'), a, b, 'uni', 0)
ph = cat(2, ph{:});
```

(elegant means: no loop. Also, `scatter` won't work for me as it does not allow different marker types)

#### Edit:

Second best solution might be

```
ph = plot([a;nan(size(a))], [b;nan(size(a))], 'o')
```

This will produce four line objects but comes at the cost of having extra `NaN` data elements. Note the `NaN` have to be added to both arguments, otherwise there would be only two line series (the second one being invisible containing only `NaN`s for one coordinate).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to plot both (or an arbitrary number) lines in one plot command. If so, you can use cellfun and input cell arrays, see example below:

```
x1 = 1:100;
x2 = 1:2:200;
y1 = rand(1,100);
y2 = rand(1,100);
X = {x1,x2};
Y = {y1,y2};
figure(1)
hold on
cellfun(@plot, X, Y)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm asking. In fact, standard plot usage using `plot([x1(:), x2(:)], [y1(:), y2(:)])` or `plot(x1, y1, 'o', x2, y2, 'x')` will generate two plot objects, no need for `cellfun`.

Comment: All I want is, starting with two vectors of same length, plot each pair of elements as a separate line object.